# Can I use BitLocker on a Windows 8 Tablet? How?

Tags: windows-8, bitlocker

I hear that [Windows 8 Pro can use full disk encryption](https://superuser.com/questions/439470/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-pro-and-windows-rt).  I also understand that Win8 is targeting the "slate" / "tablet" form factor specifically.  But all my previous experience with BitLocker requires you to put in some kind of PIN or password at boot time -- how can I do this without a (hardware) keyboard?

[This preview](http://liliputing.com/2012/10/hp-elitepad-900-windows-8-tablet-with-smart-jackets-to-add-functionality.html) of an upcoming Win8 tablet mentions BitLocker but doesn't address the PIN issue.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There are two versions of Windows 8, Windows 8 *Pro*, and Windows 8 *RT*. Pro is targeted at desktops/laptops, and RT is targeted at slates/tablets.

Comment: Per the question I linked to, RT doesn't support domain joining or group policy -- does that mean that I can't have Win8 tablets on a corporate network?  That seems, uh, really broken.

Comment: If they don't support that, then no. You can look into Windows 8 pro tablets though. I think Intel is about to release one.

Comment: @Coderer you can have Windows 8 tablets on your corporate network _if_ they're running the full Windows 8. Some tablets only run Windows RT, which is more stripped down, but many tablets will support full-blown Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows RT includes its own (non-BitLocker) device encryption, similar to Windows Mobile before it. Without a device at hand, unfortunately I don't have the exact sequence of steps needed to enable it.

Using BitLocker with Windows 8 on a tablet currently [requires the use of TPM, a startup key, or an external USB keyboard](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/35383ebf-0809-464a-b5ce-0cc465670c9e).

Comment: So in summary, no, I'm not missing anything, this is a known issue, and there is no current solution -- to boot a BL-encrypted slate from full power-down, you need to carry something else (a "key", or a keyboard) with you.  Oh well, doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: You've got it exactly. If you carry a USB key to start the tablet, don't carry it _with_ the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Hello from the future!

It looks like this issue took a while to gain traction, but has been addressed, to some extent, quite recently.  [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/07/14/bitlocker-pin-on-surface-pro-3-and-other-tablets.aspx) provides two key facts:

- If you have a TPM, boot-time authentication (PIN) is not very important on most tablets (although, read article for caveats)
- If you use a boot-time PIN, some devices are now providing boot-time on-screen keyboard (like the Surface Pro 3)

I have read a few forum posts where some other tablets are getting BIOS patches that will enable a boot-time OSK.  I think that's the best solution going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you'll either need to upgrade your Windows 8 to pro or encrypt the drivers on a Win 8 pro pc. After that it should read them fine. This is for 8 and 8 pro, no idea about RT

Comment: OK so, supposing I have a Windows 8 tablet *without hardware keyboard*, and I upgrade to Pro.  Can I unlock it *without carrying any extra devices* or do I need to tote something (keyboard, hardware key, etc) with me, as the other answer states?