# What are the different versions of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Windows 8 Pro and Windows RT?](https://superuser.com/questions/439470/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-pro-and-windows-rt)

I know that in the past there have been Home Editions, and Pro Editions, and Starter Editions, but what about this time around? All I keep hearing about is the Pro Version, and the tablet version. Is that it?

Or are there more?

Comment: Also see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/439470/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-pro-and-windows-rt/439473#439473

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four editions of Windows this time around: Windows RT, Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro and Windows 8 Enterprise.

- **Windows RT** is designed for ARM CPUs, at the moment tablets only. It will run the new Modern UI apps, but will not run Desktop programs from previous versions of Windows.
- **Windows 8** is the 'standard' version for x86 and x86-64 (32-bit and 64-bit) CPUs, currently used on tablets, laptops and desktops, to replace Home and Home Premium. It will run both Modern UI apps and traditional Desktop programs. Most programs that run on Windows 7 will work here.
- **Windows 8 Pro** is the 'premium' edition for x86 and x86-64 (32-bit and 64-bit) CPUs, currently used on tablets, laptops and desktops, to replace Professional and Ultimate. It has a couple extra features on top of Windows 8 (standard).
- **Windows 8 Enterprise** is the business/volume licence edition, to replace Enterprise. As a home user, don't worry about this. It is similar to Pro, but missing media center. One notable feature is Windows-To-Go, which lets you boot off a flash drive.

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/compare) has a feature comparison of the different versions. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions) goes into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I believe everything you need to know is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Comment: While that link is certainly helpful, it would be preferable to summarize the most relevant parts here.

Comment: @Dennis Alright. Bob already did that for me, but I will be sure to do that in my future answers.