# Which Windows 8 edition should I update to from Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I have Windows 7 Home Premium on my laptop, need to upgrade to Windows 8.

If there were a *Windows 8 Home Premium* midway between those two I would've chosen that... but there are only two **Windows 8** or **Windows 8 Pro**, so I'm a bit confused, as I don't want the former to be like **Windows 7 Basic**. My usage is mostly coding, game development, mid-performance gaming and some benchmarking and video editing.

Your recommendations please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Windows 8 Pro and Windows RT?](http://superuser.com/questions/439470/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-pro-and-windows-rt)

Comment: It is not a duplicate

Comment: @pratyushnalam while the wording and the title may not be the same, the answers are the same.

Comment: The above question is which Windows 8 edition. The question you gave a link to is regarding Windows RT and Windows 8 Pro. Windows RT doesn't come into the picture when talking about upgrades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between now and January 31, 2013, you can [update to Windows 8 Pro for $40](http://windowsupgradeoffer.com/). That is your best option until the promotion expires.

[This Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx) goes into detail on the different versions of Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a [chart from Microsoft](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx) outlining the differrences between the versions of Windows 8, Pro, and RT. Because you can [upgrade to Win8 Pro for only $40](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro) for the digital download version, that is likely your best (and cheapest) option.

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════╦═════╦═════╗
║ Feature Name                                   ║ Win 8 ║ Pro ║ RT  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Upgrades from Windows 7 Starter,               ║   x   ║  x  ║     ║
║ Home Basic, Home Premium                       ║       ║     ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Upgrades from Windows 7 Professional, Ultimate ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Start screen, Semantic Zoom, Live Tiles        ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Windows Store                                  ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Apps (Mail, Calendar, People, Messaging,       ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
║ Photos, SkyDrive, Reader, Music, Video)        ║       ║     ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Microsoft Office RT included with OS           ║       ║     ║  x  ║
║ (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote)             ║       ║     ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Internet Explorer 10                           ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Device encryption                              ║       ║     ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Connected standby                              ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Microsoft account                              ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Desktop                                        ║   x   ║  x  ║  *  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ SmartScreen                                    ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Windows Update                                 ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Enhanced task manager                          ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Switch languages on the fly w/ language packs  ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Better multiple monitor support                ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Storage spaces                                 ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Windows Media Player                           ║   x   ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Exchange ActiveSync                            ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ File history                                   ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ ISO / VHD mount                                ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Mobile broadband features                      ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Picture password                               ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Play To device                                 ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Remote Desktop client                          ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Refresh and reset your PC                      ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Snap                                           ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Touch and Thumb keyboard                       ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Trusted boot                                   ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ VPN Client                                     ║   x   ║  x  ║  x  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ BitLocker and BitLocker To Go                  ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Client Hyper-V                                 ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Domain join                                    ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Encrypting File System                         ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Group Policy                                   ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Remote Desktop host                            ║       ║  x  ║     ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════╩═════╩═════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the different editions of Windows 8 using [this table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart) and then select what version you want, depending on what features you may require.

Windows 8 Pro is also currently on an upgrade offer at http://windowsupgradeoffer.com for $40 until 31st January and it would be a good option if you currently have a copy of Windows 7 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an official post by Microsoft

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx