# How do I encrypt a folder in Windows RT?

Tags: encryption, windows-rt, microsoft-surface

I'm apparently unable to encrypt folders on my Surface RT. When I view the properties of a folder, and then go to the "Advanced Attributes", the option to "Encrypt contents to secure data" is disabled. I've tried this on various folders, all with the same results.

Is there a setting somewhere I need to enable to allow this feature?

Comment: Everything on the drive is already encrypted. Do you have a use-case not covered by BitLocker? Then please expand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Windows RT does not have support for the [Encrypting File System (EFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System), or even proper UI support for BitLocker. It does however have BitLocker-based **device encryption** enabled out of the box using the [Trusted Platform Module (TPM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) chip installed, and commands such as *manage-bde* are still supported.

Comment: *manage-bed* is supported in RT, but it is reduced functionality. A number of its commands will indicate that they are not supported in this version of the operating system.